# How to open multiple links and extract table data from these links in Python?

Tags: python, html, csv, href, export-to-csv

All the first row's elements are links to subsequent pages from where I need to take the information. The main problem is to open these links in python. I need to print that information to a csv file later. [Here is image how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH25N.jpg).
How can I open multiple links in Python? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at scrapy.

Answer (score 1):

`requests` and `beautifulsoup` will do the job easily

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get('http://firstpage.com/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('a')
for link in links:
    print(link['href'])
```

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/